# Blowing Up the Aswan Dam: How Many People Get Flooded?

Tags: warfare, history, hydrology

Let's say in some war scenario, an enemy of Egypt decides to fire a missile which can crack the Aswan High Dam. How many Egyptians would become casualties? You can interpret that to include people rendered homeless by the flood waters, if you choose.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'm hoping this question doesn't get anyone put on a watch list. Again.

Comment: https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/threads/the-aswan-high-dam-is-destroyed-by-a-nuclear-weapon.9465/

Comment: Attacking a population of non-combatants by deliberately attempting to flood them seems 1) A clearly criminal act that will get the appropriate leader eventually dragged to The Hague to stand trial, and 2) Foolishly disproportional from a military perspective - a multitude of unexpected consequences will quickly spiral, perhaps gaining Egypt new allies and resources and strength. The entire point of professional military officer training is to constrain consequences and manage risks, not roll the dice. Rolling the dice is how you lose.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] and find out [what WB.SE is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) before you ask questions. This is question has no obvious worldbuilding context. What is the worldbuilding problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you want an idea on how that kind of thing gets woven into fiction, please have a look at 1988 book by John Randall that addressed a dam blown up along the Colorado River.  The name of the book is [The Jihad Ultimatum](https://www.amazon.com/Jihad-Ultimatum-John-D-Randall/dp/093307123X).  Is that the kind of story that you are trying to tell?

Comment: @user535733: It is definitely not a criminal act; indeed, it is a most honorable practice, as [exemplified by the English Royal Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Chastise) less than 80 years ago. The [heroic audacious leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Gibson) of the dam busters got the Victoria Cross for successfully executing this daring operation.

Comment: @user535733: You might note that the Chinese (at least) once did this to their own dams: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_Banqiao_Dam_failure